# ssh-agent issue on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, ssh, raspbian

Weird thing - on my raspberry pi running raspbian buster i can't seem to use the ssh agent. I know that in some systems you have to manually eval the `ssh-agent` output unlike on things like OSX where `ssh-add` works out of the box. But for some reason on my Pi this is not working so I am getting the correct output from `ssh-agent` but when i try to then run `ssh-add` i still receieve the connection error:

```
eval ssh-agent -s
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-8Dc0i8qfejW0/agent.7476; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=7477; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 7477;
root@raspberrypi:~/git# ssh-add ~/.ssh/githubpersonal
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When you do :

```
eval ssh-agent -s
```

You are not setting environment variables. You need to do

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```